# Importing DLL using a module definition file (.def)

Tags: c, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I want to create and ship a windows C library. I've read there are two ways to do it, one using __declspec(dllexport) and __declspec(dllimport) in the header files and one using a module definition file ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll?view=vs-2019)). I don't want to modify the header files so I've opted for the second one and created the library, which I've confirmed it exports the required symbols.

Now, when I ship it:

1. do the header files still need to have __declspec(dllimport) in front of every exported function so that clients can use it?
2. do I need to ship the module definition file along with the dll, or will the .lib file suffice?

I've of course tested both with a toy example and I believe the answers to both my questions are No, but I'd like to confirm that with an experienced developer before I ship anything out.

I've found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/importing-using-def-files?view=vs-2019) article but it's badly written and I don't make any sense out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just give your clients the .h file(s), the .lib import library, and the .dll file itself.  They don't need the .def file.

If I recall, the declspec import thing allows for a minor optimization by the linker.  Something about the import table.   I'll look that up later and update the answer if I can find it.

Comment: Not defining as DLL exported the functions in the header files will add extra instructions accessing the functions because the code will be linked through the jump table (that is the import table anyway). It works this way the linker insert in the jump table (import table) the adrress of DLL code, user code call the jump table address finding a jump to the real location as code. Defining imports links the user code directly with DLL location bypassing jump table.

Comment: @Frankie_C - yes. that's what I was trying to lookup.  Thanks for clarifying.